# Class/metaclass method decorator for derived class

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, metaclass

I have a metaclass that defines a class level attribute which should be unique for each subclass but shared across instances of each subclass.

```
class MetaValidator(type):
    def __new__(
             cls, name, bases, dct
    ):
        new_cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        new_cls.valid_funcs = []
        return new_cls
```

Now I'd like to implement a decorator that appends the decorated class method to valid_funcs within the derived class. However because the derived class is still being defined I don't have a reference to the derived decorator so I end up appending to the base class. Here's my code:

```
class Validator(object, metaclass=MetaValidator):

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, f):
        cls.valid_funcs.append(f)
        return f

    def _validate(self, **kwargs):
        for f in self.valid_funcs:
            params = inspect.signature(f).parameters.keys()
            f_kwargs = {name: kwargs[name] for name in params}
            f(**f_kwargs)

    def validate(self, **kwargs):
        self._validate(**kwargs)

class A(Validator):

    @staticmethod
    @Validator.add
    def test_func(x):
        return x

class B(Validator):

    @staticmethod
    @Validator.add
    def test_func(x, y):
        return x, y

a = A()
a.validate(x="In A")
b = B()
b.validate(x="In B", y=" Called with arg y")

print(Validator.valid_funcs)
print(a.valid_funcs)
print(b.valid_funcs)
```

This prints:

```
[<function A.test_func at 0x7f0189d4fc80>, 
<function B.test_func at 0x7f0189d4fd08>]
[]
[]
```

I want:

```
[]
[<function A.test_func at 0x7f0189d4fc80>]
[<function B.test_func at 0x7f0189d4fd08>]
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you are using the metaclass? why not simply add the class attribute using a class decorator?

Comment: I can do that as well but then I'd have to add the decorator to each derived class which is more cumbersome. It also doesn't help the main issue of the @add decorator. If using a decorator instead of the metaclass helps then I'd be open to it.

Comment: if you are using python 3.6+ you don't need to do that. you can use the `__subclass_init__` instead. much easier.

Comment: Whoops sorry: `__init_subclass__` ( I always have to look it up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class object *yet* when decorators on functions in the class body are executed. The class body is executed first, *then* the class is created.

Instead of having the decorator look for a class attribute to mutate, add an attribute to a decorated function object. The metaclass, *or the `_validate()` implementation* then looks for any objects with this attribute and adds them to the list once the class object has been created.

I'm going to assume you'd want to retain the order in which the decorators would have added the decorated items to the list:

```
from itertools import count

class Validator(metaclass=MetaValidator):
    @classmethod
    def add(cls, f):
        _count = getattr(Validator.add, '_count', None)
        if _count is None:
            _count = Validator.add.__func__._count = count()
        f._validator_function_id = next(_count)
        return f
```

and in the metaclass:

```
class MetaValidator(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        new_cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        registered = []
        for v in dct.values():
            id = getattr(v, '_validator_function_id', None)
            if id is None and isinstance(v, (staticmethod, classmethod)):
                # unwrap staticmethod or classmethod decorators
                id = getattr(v.__func__, '_validator_function_id', None)
            if id is not None:
                registered.append((id, v))
        new_cls.valid_funcs = [f for _, f in sorted(registered)]
        return new_cls
```

Note that if you are using Python 3.6 or newer, then you don't need a metaclass at all any more. You can put the same logic into the [`class.__init_subclass__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__).

Note that this registers **unbound objects**. For `staticmethod` objects, that means the call will fail with:

```
TypeError: <staticmethod object at 0x10d1b7048> is not a callable object
```

You perhaps want to register the `__func__` attribute in that case, or use `.__get__` to 'bind' the object to something (a `staticmethod` ignores the binding context anyway)`.

If you bind explicitly, in the `_validate()` method, then you don't actually have to use `staticmethod` objects:

```
def _validate(self, **kwargs):
    for f in self.valid_funcs:
        bound = f.__get__(self)
        signature = inspect.signature(bound)
        bound(**{name: kwargs[name] for name in signature.parameters})
```

Now `@validator.add` will work with `staticmethod`, `classmethod` and regular functions.

And if you have the `_validate()` method look for the methods, then binding can be done *for you*. You can choose to support inheritance here by just using `dir()` and `getattr()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import count


class Validator:
    @classmethod
    def add(cls, f):
        _count = getattr(Validator.add, '_count', None)
        if _count is None:
            _count = Validator.add.__func__._count = count()
        f._validator_function_id = next(_count)
        return f

    def _list_validators(self):
        objects = (getattr(self, name) for name in dir(self))
        return sorted(
            (o for o in objects if hasattr(o, '_validator_function_id')),
            key=attrgetter('_validator_function_id'))

    def _validate(self, **kwargs):
        for f in self._list_validators():
            signature = inspect.signature(f)
            f(**{name: kwargs[name] for name in signature.parameters})
```

`getattr()` gives you a bound object, no further binding necessary.

Answer (score 0):

While having the metaclass `__new__` handle adding functions to `valid_funcs` is an option, another option would be to inject `valid_funcs` into the namespace of the class body before the class even exists, using [`__prepare__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#preparing-the-class-namespace):

```
class MetaValidator(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, name, bases, **kwds):
        ns = super().__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)
        ns['valid_funcs'] = []
        return ns

def register(func_list):
    def inner_register(func):
        func_list.append(func)
        return func
    return inner_register

class A(metaclass=MetaValidator):
    @register(valid_funcs)
    def method(self):
        ...
```

I'd probably skip all the metaclass stuff and require classes to do `valid_funcs = []` themselves, though. The additional complexity of a metaclass isn't worth it just to save one line of boilerplate per class.